# How do I get a file's icon in Java? (MacOS) duplicate but not updated

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos

Trying to find a solution to get an executable icon from OSProcess.getPath()
On Windows, Mac and *nix

```
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
  Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
}
```

Works fine on Windows.

```
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  Icon icon = fc.getUI().getFileView(fc).getIcon(file);
  // or even
  icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
}
```

Always returns the default File Icon on Mac !?

Did implement this as temprary workaround on Mac
(maybe someone could help me to get it 100% ACCURATE:)

```
// macOS-specific icon retrieval
// maybe find a simpler solution
// Todo : fix various icons like VLC ...
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC && fullProcessPathName.contains("MacOS")) {
    String iconPathSplit = fullProcessPathName.split("MacOS")[0];
    String plistFilePath = iconPathSplit + "Info.plist";

    File pListFile = getFileWithSpaceUri(plistFilePath);
    if (pListFile.exists()) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = Plist.load(plistFilePath);
        String cFBundleIconFile = (String) properties.get("CFBundleIconFile");
        String iconFilePath = iconPathSplit + "Resources/" + cFBundleIconFile;

        // Ensure file path ends with ".icns"
        if (!iconFilePath.endsWith(".icns")) {
                        iconFilePath += ".icns";
        }

        File iconFile = getFileWithSpaceUri(iconFilePath);
        if (iconFile.canRead()) {
            List<BufferedImage> iconImages = new IcnsImageParser().getAllBufferedImages(iconFile);
            Optional<BufferedImage> resultImage = iconImages
                .stream().parallel()
                .filter(num -> num.getRaster().getHeight() == 32).findAny();

            if (resultImage.isPresent()) {
                BufferedImage bufferedImageR = resizeImage(resultImage.get(), 26, 26);
                Icon icon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImageR);
                iconCacheMap.put(fullProcessPathName, icon);
                return icon;
            }

        }
    }
}
    /**
     *  Workaround to open folders files with spaces
     *  @param filePath
     *  @return file
     */
    private static File getFileWithSpaceUri(String filePath) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI outputURI = new URI(("file:///" + filePath.replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
        File outputFile = new File(outputURI);
        return outputFile;
    }
```